Why do I get 9V while the figure in the datasheet says I should get ~4V?
How do I get ~4V from Figure 9.1 below, when I simulate it I get around 9V. Am I doing something wrong?
The source of the original schematic "Figure 9-1" below is the Texas Instruments BQ34Z100-R2 fuel gauge IC datasheet found here.




EDIT 1:



What MOSFET are you using?

You need a load. Put a resistor from the output to ground. Try 100-500 ohms.

Also, despite the load resistance you also need to use a real MOSFET model.

@Mattman944 see edit 1, I get 32mV

Here is a realistic simulation using the 2N7002 as shown in the datasheet
example:

Voltage is 4.55V at 27°C with some temperature variation using the MOSFET model given.
The ~1.7V drop below the zener voltage is from the Vgs required to get the output current (in this case I've used a 10kΩ resistor so the current drain is about 450uA).
In practice that value will vary with both the current and with the individual MOSFET so it's very approximate.
Here is the variation with load and temperature (typical):

To estimate the variation from MOSFET to MOSFET, the Vgs(th) for 250uA drain current is from 1V to 2.5V with 1.6V typical. We are seeing close to the typical value of drop (1.7V) in the nominal simulation. So we might expect another ~ +/-1V variation potentially, so approaching 3.0V minimum output and 6V maximum output, worst case.
There will also be some variation with the supply voltage, but that effect is relatively small until the supply gets close to the zener voltage since the gate draws virtually no current.

You can think of this as a zener+resistor regulator with a source-follower current amplifier.
It's more common (and usually much better) use a BJT as an emitter-follower rather than a MOSFET source-follower since the output voltage will be much better defined.


Am I doing something wrong.


You selected a 4-terminal MOSFET (nmos4 from the LTspice library) but you didn't select any particular model which means you'll be using the ideal (default) model
You left the bulk (one in the middle) pin floating
You left the source pin floating as well i.e. no load resistor

If you connect the bulk to the source and put a load resistor (i.e. across the source pin and GND) you'll get a source follower.

See Edit 1, I get 32mV. What does a source follower do, does is "follow" the drain or gate?

@JoeyB: Pick a real FET like a 2N7002. The ideal model will not work here.

Okay now it works, but how does it work. The FET has a drop of 8V, the gate sits at 6V due to the zener. So how it the FET producing the 4V at the source?

@JoeyB You should ask that as a new question. This question is about why your simulation didn't match the expected results.
