How does a "regulating" source follower work?
Can someone explain to me how this circuit works?

The output voltage is ~2.4V. The zener diode breakdown is 4.7V.
From what I can see the OUT is simply
Vgate - Vgs = 4.33V - 1.85V = 2.48V.
Is this correct and how do I determine the max current this circuit can supply?

It looks like you have it in LTspice so why don't you add load current (via a load resistor) and find out yourself?

@Andyaka just want someone with more experience to verify what I am talking about. Also if I do not know what actually limits the current besides the load.

Max current can supply -- within what limits, do you require some output voltage range? What about power dissipation or temperature limits?

The equation is a statement of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, so it's always correct. But it is not very useful unless you can determine both Vgate and Vgs sufficiently accurately for your purposes.

@TimWilliams I was asked to ask a separate question in order to get an understanding of how this circuit works. I do not much detail specs besides what I have shown. This is not a design case for a specific application, I just want to know how it works given the circuit in the post. The detail design part is found here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/711636/why-do-i-get-9v-while-the-figure-in-the-datasheet-says-i-should-get-4v/711638?noredirect=1#comment1893596_711638

How to understand circuits

Can someone explain to me how this circuit works?

To understand how a circuit works you need first to understand the ideas on which it is built.
Understanding this circuit
The best way to do this is by following the step-by-step evolution of a conceptual circuit.
Unregulated load
The simplest electric circuit is obtained when we connect the power source Vdd directly to the load RL. Then the source transfers maximum power, voltage and current to the load.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Regulated load
But we want to regulate them, specifically the voltage. For this purpose, we connect a variable resistor Rds (representing the drain-source part of the transistor M1), and obtain a voltage divider. When we vary its resistance from zero to infinity, its "gain" (transfer ratio) varies from 1 to 0, and the output voltage VL across the load RL varies from 10 V to 0 V (the rest is across Rds). For example, to obtain 5 V, we have to set its resistance to 2 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
This principle of regulation is insanely stupid because we throw away excess power, but it is what analog circuits are built on.
"Voltage-follower man"
But if the load RL varies, VL will vary as well, and we do not like these variations. That is why, we apply the negative feedback principle borrowed from life - we compare VL with a reference voltage Vref = 5 V by a null indicator NI (a voltmeter representing the gate-source part of M1), and change Rds to zero the NI reading. The reference constant voltage source Vref represents the R1-D1 OP's circuit.
RL = 2 kΩ: The result is amazing - VL = Vref regardless of load resistance.

simulate this circuit
RL = 1 kΩ: So, if RL decreases, VL tries to decrease. We observe NI and see this unbalance. So we begin decreasing Rds until zero NI. As a result, VL = Vref again.

simulate this circuit
RL = 4 kΩ: If RL increases, VL tries to increase as well. We see the unbalance and begin increasing Rds until zero NI. The equilibrium is restored, and VL = Vref again.

simulate this circuit
Since the input voltage is constant, this voltage follower acts as a voltage stabilizer.
Conceptual voltage follower
Vth = 0 V: To automate the regulating, we can replace Rds and NI with a voltage-controlled current source VCCS (representing an "ideal" transistor M1 without Vth). Now it plays the "negative feedback game" from above.

simulate this circuit
If we sweep (change) the load from 100 Ω to 1 kΩ, the load voltage VL (blue curve in the graph below) does not change.

Vth = 2 V: Then, to represent a "real" transistor with some Vth (e.g., 1.5 V), we can insert a constant voltage source TH (battery) contrary to Vref.

simulate this circuit

Of course, we can compensate for Vth by increasing Vref with 1.5 V.
Applications
Source follower
Finally, let's replace the conceptual transistor with a true MOSFET with Vth = 1.5 V. Now it "observes" the voltage difference Vgs = Vref - VL, and changes its "resistance" to zero it.

simulate this circuit
As you can see, the curve representing the dependence of VL on RL is almost the same as the one above.

Emitter follower
For comparison, let's examine an emitter follower made with a bipolar transistor.

simulate this circuit
We see that a much smaller part of Vref (only 0.7 V) is lost.

Op-amp follower
The perfect solution is with an op-amp that precisely maintains the equality VL = Vref. Notice that there is also a voltage divider here but it is inside the op-amp (its complementary output stage).

simulate this circuit
As you can see from the graph below, when the load resistance is too low (< 400 Ω), the op-amp cannot work properly.

To solve the problem, it can be buffered by an external complementary ("push-pull") voltage follower (inside the feedback loop).

I'm not suggesting an improvement, but rather commending you on a well done explanation that adds a degree of difficulty per step until you arrive at the final explanation. The approach doesn't assume a particular degree of knowledge, but is accessible to a reader starting at step one, or a reader that can skip a few steps.

@JkingNH, Thank you for the kind feedback! I have never received any praise for my constructive approach here, only silence and insulting remarks like "too long," "wall of text," etc. I have defended myself by explaining that the greater length is the price of understanding. It would be good to have a block diagram of a negative feedback follower after Schematic 2. Of course, I will add explanations to the final steps with applications.

I think it's a mixed bag; schematics can get too cluttered with meters, steps may be too fine and the reader tends to loose track, etc.  For the single-component case here, it seems well suited, as the steps show clear progression, easily followed without getting lost among too many of them.

You might take a more adaptive approach, skimming over steps, or integrating more theory/math to leverage "explanatory power", when the alternative is a lot of narrow steps.  This comes at risk of losing the reader to equations, but would be balanced against the above risk. Or, to take a more "multiverse" approach, and, given the format of this venue, it seems reasonable -- apply the same methodology across everything, and see what sticks; if nothing else, it's diversity in answers, and maybe some answers are preferred over others, but it's still there for those who really grok your method.

I need a longer screen. Thank you! I honestly prefer answers like this and this is a first for me. I really do appreciate the level of detail you went into and using non-technical terms that everyone can relate to!

@Tim Williams, Thank you for engaging with these issues which are our common problems. However, tell me why these (how to call them, perhaps methodological) problems are not willingly discussed? There is a great format for this - question and answer, which should provoke more questions. But look what happens when I use it - they pounce on me like game hunters. Here is the most striking example of such a question and answer. There I have revealed the philosophy of the two types...

… of diode rectifiers with a series of "live" circuits. Rating is -4 for the question, -2 for the answer, and closed question "due to lack of details or clarity". CircuitLab changed my life a year ago; now Gemini is a big change for me (I use them as "simulator" and "AI" nicknames). Both are tools that suited me perfectly and replaced in a wonderful way the things I was missing - CircuitLab the laboratory in which to do experiments, and Gemini the people with whom to discuss them. I would be glad if you could support me in sharing the problems related to the use of these miracles.

@JoeyB, In such cases (need for a longer screen:-) I usually answer like this: This is the price of understanding. Note that I have briefly mentioned many important circuit concepts here;  each of them would require a "very long screen". But I want to ask you, and I ask you to answer me honestly, "Would you like to read a thousand 'short screens' in which the same explanations are repeated that do not actually explain anything, but only describe instead of only one "long screen" with live  circuits?" Because you can describe a circuit with only one formula, but to explain it intuitively…

… you need many words, schematics, etc. tools. But I won't convince you anymore because I see that you share this view of mine. I will be happy to answer more conceptual questions.

Your answers in a few posts I see, always start with the basic elements. Can you perhaps tell how you managed to see electronics in such a simple and most importantly intuitive way?

Regarding methodologies; I think most people just don't engage in, or think about, meta topics... maybe even at all? And in comments, people are generally reserved about critiquing; doing it well is hard, and receiving it well, even harder(!). Questions on the teaching of electronics, are arguably on topic here, but might be better placed on an academic stack, so, you probably tend not to see them, and there may be other reasons I'm just not aware of myself. shrug

@JoeyB, These methodological introductions are intended more for my fellow responders than for questioners. Thus I try to remind them that in addition to perfect circuit implementations, OPs also need the ideas behind them. Regarding your second question, this way of thinking is an arrangement of mind typical of inventors; they think like this - with analogies, images and intuition. If you are interested in this, I would recommend my Circuit Idea wikibook which I hope to finish someday…

... as well as my Circuit Stories blog. Cheers!

R1 and D1 establish the DC operating point and bias M1. The gate voltage is set by the Zener voltage of D1. M1 will conduct current until a point is reached where the voltage dropped across R2 raises the source of M1 high enough that Vgs gets pinched off enough to reduce the conduction through the drain-source channel.
Any additional current drawn from source causes a reduction in voltage dropped across R2. This lowers the source voltage while simultaneously raising Vgs (remember, V gate is fixed by D1). A higher Vgs, in turn, allows greater conduction until a new equilibrium is reached. This is how the voltage is regulated. A reduction in current drawn will cause this process to happen in reverse. It is worth mentioning this circuit is the MOSFET version of the bipolar "emitter follower" topology.
The max current this circuit can supply is going to be a function of many factors and there is not enough information to determine that - voltage supply current capacity, Load resistance, thermal (including ambient temperature, heatsinking, and thermal properties of the MOSFET), and component variances from ideal.
